# Java Inheritance of Static Variable

Tags: java, inheritance, static-variables

I have a static variable in my Base123 class

```
class Base123 {
    public static int statvar;
}
```

and I have a derived class, `Inheritance111`, which extends `Base123`

```
public class Inheritance111 extends Base123 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Inheritance111.statvar);
        System.out.println(Base123.statvar);
        Base123.statvar=10;
        System.out.println(Inheritance111.statvar);
        System.out.println(Base123.statvar);
        System.out.println(statvar);
        Inheritance111.statvar=20;
        System.out.println(Inheritance111.statvar);
        System.out.println(Base123.statvar);
        System.out.println(statvar);
    }
}
```

I obtained the output for above code as :

> 0 0 10 10 10 20 20 20

For one class, the static variable is shared across all the objects of the class. But when a class is extended, is the inherited variable in the subclass also the same variable? As the changes made using

```
Inheritance111.statvar=20;
```

is changing the value of `Base123.statvar`.

Comment: static variables are not inherited. doesn't mean it can't be accessed. have you tried to do it like that? what result did you get?

Comment: Static variable is shared across all the objects of that class since it belong to the class information.

Comment: @Stultuske If I give System.out.println(statvar); I see the value of the static variable from inside the Derived class.

Comment: @Stultuske how would you call this then? `sharing` between classes?

Comment: @Eugene why would I have to give a name to it? static members are not inherited. that doesn't mean they can't be used. that does mean, however, that when they're re-defined in the subclass, they don't overwrite, but hide the original.

Comment: @Stultuske I do understand that if it is redefined in the subclass, static members are not overriden, but hidden. But here I am not re defining. I have only one declaration of the variable in the base class. If the variable is not inherited, how am I able to refer to it without using the class name ? As in the previous comment, I am able to print it using System.out.println(statvar); inside main method of the sub class.

Comment: you can reference, because an instance of a subclass IS per definition, an instance of the super class. All I'm saying, is that with static members there is no inheritance.

Comment: @Eugene From the code I am trying, since the change in the variable referred to as 'Inheritance111.statvar' is reflecting to the variable 'Base123.statvar', both seem to be the same,or  the variable is being shared between the classes. Is it all because I should not have declared the variable as public in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it refers to same variable as Super class even if you call variable from sub class like `Inheritance111.statvar=20;`.
 You can refer to this JavaDoc [static fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e12110)